# Setting custom Application Bar buttons in DatePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, datepicker, toolkit

I have DatePicker from this article:http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization. There is one quote:

> The toolkit provides the necessary icons, but you have to copy them from the PhoneToolkitSample project. They must be named "ApplicationBar.Cancel.png" and "ApplicationBar.Check.png", and the build action must be "Content"!

I don't know how to set build action as "Content" in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone 7. Does somebody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is '12, but its exactly the same.

[image]

Add your image to your project.  Make sure it's selected, then open the Properties window.  Under "Build Action", select "Content".